# If $0\le a,b,c\le 1$, then $\frac a{1+bc}+\frac b{1+ac}+\frac c{1+ab}\le 2$

Tags: inequality, convexity-inequality

> If $a,b,c$ are real numbers such that $0\le a,b,c\le 1$, then $$\frac a{1+bc}+\frac b{1+ac}+\frac c{1+ab}\le 2.$$

I did the following:
Take $f(x)=\frac {x^2}{x+p},\ (p=abc)$ which is convex for $0\le x\le 1$. Therefore $$\begin{align}\frac {f(a)+f(b)+f(c)}3\le f(\frac {a+b+c}3)\Rightarrow\frac {a^2}{a+abc}+\frac {b^2}{b+abc}+\frac {c^2}{c+abc}\le \frac {(a+b+c)^2}{(a+b+c)+3abc}.\end{align}$$
How do I prove that the RHS is less than or equal to 2?

Comment: Note that $f$ is convex implies that $f(a)+f(b)+f(c)\ge3f(\frac{a+b+c}3)$.

Comment: @Macavity oops..sorry for the mistake..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $a,b,c \in [0,1] \implies abc \le ab,bc,ca$.

Thus, $\displaystyle \frac{a}{1+bc}+\frac{b}{1+ac}+\frac{c}{1+ab} \le \frac{a}{1+abc}+\frac{b}{1+abc}+\frac{c}{1+abc} = \frac{a+b+c}{1+abc}$

Since, $\displaystyle a,b,c \in [0,1] \implies a(1-b)(1-c) \ge 0 \implies \sum\limits_{cyc} a(1-b)(1-c) \ge 0 \\ \implies a+b+c + 3abc \ge 2(ab+bc+ac)$

$$\begin{align} \implies 2(abc+1) &\ge 2abc + 2 + 2(ab+bc+ac) - 3abc - (a+b+c) \\ &= a+b+c + abc + 2(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)  \\ &\ge a+b+c \end{align}$$

Thus, $\displaystyle \frac{a}{1+bc}+\frac{b}{1+ac}+\frac{c}{1+ab} \le \frac{a+b+c}{1+abc} \le 2$

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(a,b,c)=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{1+bc}$.

Thus, $f$ is a convex function of $a$, of $b$ and of $c$.

Id est, $$\max_{\{a,b,c\}\subset[0,1]}f=\max_{\{a,b,c\}\subset\{0,1\}}f=f(1,1,0)=2.$$

Comment: IMHO you should not answer duplicates of earlier questions. However, your approach would survive the competition in any of the dupe targets. It seems to me that the best way to deal with this would be for you to post this as an answer to whichever version survives the dupe voting, and delete other copies. Asking for the diamond bearers to merge the threads is also an option.