# Proof inequality $a,b, c \in [0,1]$

Tags: inequality

Let $a , b , c \in [0,1]$. Prove that $\frac{a}{1+bc}+\frac{b}{1+ac}+\frac{c}{1+ab} \leq2$.

Thanks Mark for your reply. I'm new to the group so I dont know how to deal with this . Anyways I tried assuming that $c=\max\{a,b,c\}$ .

I also tried applying AM-GM on $(1+bc)$ but I got no result.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1086580/42969.

Comment: I don't think that it's a duplicate because my solution is different from the solutions of the linked topics.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I'm really puzzled by your comment. Why would that imply that the question is not a duplicate?