# Algebraic solution to $\frac{a}{1+bc}+ \frac{b}{1+ac}+ \frac{c}{1+ab} \le 2$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

With $0 \le a \le b \le c \le 1$.

I know that this question has been answered here : [If $0\le a,b,c\le 1$, then $\frac a{1+bc}+\frac b{1+ac}+\frac c{1+ab}\le 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086580/if-0-le-a-b-c-le-1-then-frac-a1bc-frac-b1ac-frac-c1ab-le-2).

But I’m looking for a solution using some simple algebra .

**My attempt:**

We know that :
$$a^2+1 \geq 2a, a^2\le bc \implies \frac{bc+1}{a}\geq 2$$
$$\iff \frac{a}{bc+1}\le \frac{1}{2}$$

But this trick doest works on:
$$ \frac{b}{1+ac} $$
Because $b^2\geq ac$

Comment: But there is already some solution using simple algebra (not Michael Rozenbergs one)

Comment: Is this a simple algebra?
$$\sum\limits_{cyc} a(1-b)(1-c) \ge 0 $$

Comment: ofcourse each term $a(1-b)(1-c)\ge 0$ so the result follows

Comment: Yassir there is an alternative way to prove $\frac{a+b+c}{1+abc}\le 2$  but its simple but lengthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you find the answer by [sciona](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/195458/sciona) difficult  and you want to avoid the use of $\sum_{cyc} a(1-b)(1-c)\ge 0$  here is an alternative approach

After [sciona](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/195458/sciona)'s  work we have to prove $$\frac{a+b+c}{1+abc}\le 2$$ $$ \iff a(1-2bc)+b+c\le 2\tag1$$  Now if

- $1-2bc\ge 0$ $$a(1-2bc)+b+c\le 1-2bc+b+c$$  Now if $1-2c\ge 0$ then $1-2bc+b+c=b(1-2c)+1+c\le 1-2c+1+c=2-c\le 2$

If $1-2c\le 0$ then $1-2bc+b+c=b(1-2c)+c+1\le c+1 \le 2$

- $1-2bc\le 0$  then $$a(1-2bc)+b+c\le b+c\le 2$$

Done!
Although this seems a lot of work the cases we took are simply intuitive

> Note:  The best way to prove is that notice Inequality (1) is a linear function in $a$ and hence its maximum  and minimum  will occur at the boundary and similarly the for $b$ and $c$ so it suffices to check when $a=b=c=0,a=1b=c=0,a=b=1c=0,a=b=c=1$

Comment: when does $\frac{a}{1+bc}+ \frac{b}{1+ac}+ \frac{c}{1+ab} = 2$??

Comment: @Yassir when $a=b=1,c=0$ upto permutation

Comment: you've made a mistake in your proof @Albus Dumbledore

Comment: I've edited it, @Albus Dumbledore

Comment: @Yassir thanks! there was a mistake in your edit too, see now

Comment: Can you check my proof that I’ve suddenly discovered it right now?
$$1+ac \geq 1 \iff \frac{1}{1+ac}\le 1$$, now since $b\le1$: $$\frac{b}{1+ac} \le 1$$ by the same method we have $$\frac{a}{1+bc} \le 1 ; \frac{c}{1+ab} \le 1 $$ adding them together $$\frac{b}{1+ac} + \frac{a}{1+bc}  + \frac{c}{1+ab} \le 3 $$

Comment: @Yassir there is nothing wrong with that but you havnt proved the stronger bound $\le 2$

Answer (score 0):

$WLOG$ $a\ge b\ge c$.

Then we have $\frac{a}{bc+1}+\frac{b}{ca+1}+\frac{c}{ab+1}\le \frac{a+b+c}{bc+1}$

so we only need to prove $\frac{a+b+c}{bc+1}\le 2$ , which is equivalent to $a+b+c\le 2bc+2$ , and this is equivalent to $(b-1)(c-1)+bc+(1-a)\ge 0$ , which is obviously true.